# How to enable Hash Index Type for embedded OrientDB Graph Databases?

Tags: orientdb

By default OrientDB is using the "SB-Tree" index¹. Is it somehow possible to change the used index type to "Hash" through Java API Calls? 
I was unable to find a way to change the selected index type.

[1] http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Indexes.html

Comment: Which Java API are you using to create indexes?

Comment: I'm not creating any index. I assumed those index types are used for internal use only.

Answer (score 1):

From Graph API, you can create a HASH_INDEX in this way

```
graph.createKeyIndex("name", Vertex.class, new Parameter("type", "UNIQUE_HASH_INDEX"));
```

Use NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX in case the index is not unique.

For more information look at the docs: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Graph-Database-Tinkerpop.html#using-indices